# XmlTextReader, if text not found

Tags: xml, vb.net, vb.net-2010

So my last XML question you guys found it right away. So I got one more.

Below is my code. What I am trying to get working is, if the XmlReader is unable to find the store number it is searching for, to display a Msgbox. Is that possible?

```
Dim store As String = "m" & Storenumber.Text
        Dim dir As String = IO.Path.GetTempPath + "\"
        Dim xmldocument As String = dir + "IpadCode.xml"
        Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(xmldocument)
        Try
            While document.Read()
                If (document.Name = store) Then
                    Output.Text = (document.ReadInnerXml)
                End If
            End While
        Catch
            MsgBox("Error pulling store codes")
        End Try
```

**EDIT**
I tried the below with no luck. It always said "Not found"

```
While document.Read()
            If (document.Name = store) Then
                Output.Text = (document.ReadInnerXml)
            Else
                MsgBox("Store not found")
                Exit Sub
            End If
```

Comment: The first example will only display the message if there's an exception (like an error reading the file). The second example will display the message if it encounters _any_ node whose name is not `store` (so, there will probably be one). What you probably want to do is remember if you found the node or not and, after the loop is finished, check if you found it and display the message if not. Sorry I'm not really experienced enough with VB to write this down as code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That at least gives me something to search and play around with.

Comment: Still unable to get. Found a few things, but not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that your code is reading the XML properly--this is just to show you how to handle the logic for displaying the message if document.Name is never = store:

```
Dim StoreFound as Boolean = False
While document.Read()
      If (document.Name = store) Then
          Output.Text = (document.ReadInnerXml)
          StoreFound = True
      End If
 End While

If StoreFound = False Then MsgBox("Store not found!")
```

Comment: Worked perfect! Thank you so much!